TLS library problem: SSL routines - postfix mail
I want to generate - fullchain-pem, privkey-pem. I have tried this method.
How do I generate fullchain.pem and privkey.pem?
I want to integrate them into my postfix to send mail with my mailserver:
here i have editet this parameters:
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/acme.sh/mail.xxxxx.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/acme.sh/mail.xxxxx.com/privkey.pem
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/acme.sh/mail.xxxxxx.com/
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/postfix/dh2048.pem
#smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/acme.sh/mail.xxxxxx.com/ca.crt

I am always getting the followong error, when I try to send the test mail in roundcube:
TLS library problem: SSL routines::tlsv1 alert unknown ca:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 48


I dont know what i am doing wrong. Please can someone give me an advice?

You are using a self-signed certificate that the peer doesn’t trust. The simplest solution to this ultimately is to use a CA-signed certificate. Everything else will cost you far more in time than it saves in money, even if feasible, which it may not be in this case.
